# In java where does the Endpoint.publish() method publish to?

Tags: jax-ws, endpoint

I've been following some JAX-WS tutorials and after using the `Endpoint.publish()` method to publish (presumably) my web-service I can successfully call it at localhost, but I'm wondering where the service is being published? I haven't configured it for any particular server or anything like that.

How does my request get directed to the web-service?

Comment: There is no `Endpoint.publish()` method.

Comment: Or rather Endpoint.publish(String s, Object o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JDK 1.6, Java has shipped with a [lightweight HTTP server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsServer.html), that's used by internal JDK components. It's also available for your use as well.

Related reading:

- [Oracle blog on the lightweight HTTP server](https://blogs.oracle.com/michaelmcm/entry/http_server_api_in_java)